# Solving for joint angles in 2-segment robot leg

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

I am trying to program a robot leg with 2 segments and two joints, such that for a given location of the foot, I can calculate the angles of both joints.

From here on out, the positive Y direction is forward, positive X is to the robot's right, and positive Z is up.

The leg has two segments- a horizontal "thigh" segment of length T, and a "calf" segment of length C. The thigh pivots horizontally (in the X-Y plane) around a hip joint, "H", and the calf pivots vertically around a knee joint, "K", at the end of the thigh.

The foot will follow a straight path in the Y direction, such that the distance in the X direction from the foot to the robot's body is constant and equal to T (Therefore, when the thigh is parallel to the X-axis, the calf is parallel to the Z axis). (The Z-coordinate of the foot is unimportant)

I apologize for the low quality of this diagram. The blue lines and letters are the axes.
[image: Diagram of the robot leg]

The following values are given:

- T- The length of the Thigh segment
- C- The length of the Calf segment
- X-coordinate of the foot (Equal to T if the x-coordinate of the hip joint is 0)
- Y-coordinate of the foot

I wish to find the following values:

- H- The angle of the hip joint
- K- The angle of the knee joint

Assume that the given coordinates of the foot are possible: That is, the foot is not so far forward or backward that the value for H or K is undefined.

I'm very sorry if I'm violating some universally accepted standards and my question makes your eyes bleed. I tried to be unambiguous, but I'm sometimes terrible at that.

Oh and I'm pretty sure that angles are usually represented by greek letters, but I don't know how to type those, so I'm sorry.

Answer (score 1):

$$x = (T+\cos{(\pi - K)})\sin{H}$$ 
$$ y= (T+\cos{(\pi -K)})cos{H}$$ 
Assuming $(x,y)=(0,0)$ when $H=0$, you still need to choose an origin point for the z axis. Now solve for K and H and you have your equations.

Using $\sin^2 + \cos^2 =1$, squaring the two equations and adding them together we get:
$$\sqrt{x^2 +y^2} = T+ \cos{(\pi - K)}, $$ and therefore $$K=\pi-\cos^{-1}{\left(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-T\right)}.$$

I'll leave it to you to solve for H.
[To get rid of K substitute in an expression for $\cos{(\pi-K)}$.]